# Import Facebook SDK inside Framework in Swift

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, frameworks

I'm developing a Swift framework and need to implement Facebook login in it.
However when I try to include the FacebookSDK into the umbrella header I get the following:

```
include of non-modular header inside framework module <MyModule>
```

I have looked at [Xcode 6 / Beta 4: using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875745/xcode-6-beta-4-using-bridging-headers-with-framework-targets-is-unsupported/24878877#24878877)

But I can't add the framework headers to my public headers as suggested in the answer. Has anyone managed to solve this, or know how to import a Framework into a Framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a workaround.

I am implementing the integration with the framework in a Objective-C file and exposing this methods to my swift.

Comment: What I did was to: implement the integration with the framework in a Objective-C file and exposing the methods to my swift.