# Non-modular header inside framework module

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoa, cocoapods

I am creating a cocoapod (framework) in swift that needs to import a 3rd party objective-c framework. However, when adding `#import <ThirdPartyFramework/ThirdPartyFramework.h>` to the umbrella file of my cocoapod, I get the following error:

```
Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'MyCocoapod'
```

I tried setting `Allow non-modular includes in framework modules` to YES but that did not resolve the error.

The ThirdPartyFramework.h header just has a bunch of imports of other headers:

```
#import <ThirdPartyFramework/Header1.h>
#import <ThirdPartyFramework/Header2.h>
...
```

I can't really edit this framework since it's from a 3rd party. Is there anything I can do to use this 3rd party framework in my swift cocoapod? Can I not modularize the header that I need to import?

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776497/include-of-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module) that the library owner needs to move the imports into a .m file, but I am not the library owner. Also, I'm using swift and the library is in objective-c so I don't really have .m files, which is why I have to import it in my umbrella file.

Using XCode 7.3