# Can't import CommonCrypto in mixed language framework

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios9, ios-frameworks

I'm building a mixed language framework. I mainly have Swift files, and a few Objective-C ones.

One of the Objective-C files is a crypto class that uses CommonCrypto.

It seems that I can't import it for some reason, even though that I can import it in a Objective-C framework.

Can someone explain to me why that is?

All the other solutions that I found talk about how to use CommonCrypto in Swift when I need to use it in Objective-C in a Swift framework.

P.S:

1. I tried adding the import in the umbrella header file like so: 
   `#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>`
   the error: `Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'name of header'`
2. This answer did not fix the problem: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776497/include-of-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module)

Comment: Where are you inserting that import directive?

Comment: @ElTomato My Objective-c class header.. also tried the umbrella header

Comment: Please file a [bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com), this is a common problem and Apple has been ignoring Common Crypto for years and it has only gotten worse with Swift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've encountered this very problem myself. Here's how you resolve it:

1. Create a module map file ([here's my file](https://gist.github.com/vmanot/1f737976e0f00aa933e3a552f415fb9b)).
2. Copy the latest `CommonCrypto.h` header.
3. Create a directory `CommonCrypto` for both these files.
4. Copy the directory (via drag-and-drop) to your project.
5. Add the directory path under **SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS** for your target framework.

This should allow you to use `import CommonCrypto` wherever you want (**for Swift**, not Objective-C).

**Edit:** Seems like I misread the question initially. You want to use CommonCrypto in Objective-C and then use that from Swift. Here's some advice: don't `#import` CommonCrypto in your public headers, but rather just internally. Wrap all your crypto-structures so that there's no public dependency for CommonCrypto whatsoever, and then just use it from Swift via the default bridging procedure.

Comment: Hey thanks! but where do I find the CommonCrypto.h ? thanks

Comment: @Fashizel: I don't think so. My advice would be to rewrite your crypto classes in Swift.

Comment: Hey! can you elaborate about stage 5? Where can I find this option? thanks.

Comment: Go to Xcode, click on your target (on the sidebar), click on **Build Settings**, and type **SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS** in the search bar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112608/discussion-between-fashizel-and-vatsal-manot).