# Include of non-modular header inside framework module with TwitterKit

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, cocoapods

I have done following things to fix this issue

1. Under build settings set 'YES' to 'Allow Non-modular includes in FrameworkModules'
2. Cleaned project
3. Really cleaned project by deleting data under
   ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*

What can I do to fix this?

[image: First]

[image: Errors]

Comment: Check these two questions -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103169/swift-compiler-error-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776497/include-of-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module

Comment: Tried everything on there. Believe me I have tried almost all solutions out there. Nothing seems to work anymore.

Comment: FYI, I am using XCode 7.3

Comment: May I know which framework you are using? If possible a github link? So that I can play around with it?

Comment: I mean the link to to download TwitterKit, the one you using.

Comment: Here

https://get.fabric.io/

Answer (score 0):

Just changed the versions of following libraries. Using old versions now.

```
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.5.5’
pod 'TwitterCore', '~> 1.11.4'
pod 'TwitterKit', '~> 1.11.4'
```