# #import "sqlite3.h" from a pod's source

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, podspec

I have a private podspec for a library that relies on Apple's sqlite3.h. Unfortunately, it fails lint:

```
- ERROR | xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose`
    for more information.
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  /Users/tewha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
    /App-cglpwsgirxhgugbbcytbhfqnbjrw/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator
    /SQLPackRat/SQLPackRat.framework/Headers/SQLPRDatabase.h:10:9: error: include of
    non-modular header inside framework module 'SQLPackRat.SQLPRDatabase':
    '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform
    /Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.3.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h' [-Werror,
    -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module]
```

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a modular include for sqlite3.h.

How do I fix this? It seems to work anyway, but I imagine this will cause trouble for me later (probably as I start to use Swift in this project).

Comment: Can you *hide* the import in SQLPRDatabase.m instead of SQLPRDatabase.h?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776497/include-of-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module

Comment: Hiding will work, yeah. It meant forward defining structs and using Foundation's int types, but that seems to work. Thanks. :)