# Swift framework error:Include of non-modular header inside framework module

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, frameworks

I create swift framework and pod 'AMap3DMap'.
My podfile is that

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
target ‘mapFrameWork’ do
pod 'AMap3DMap'
pod 'AFNetworking' 
end
```

when it did finished but i found that error:

[image]

i set the

[image]

but it does't work.
now what should i do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include of non-modular header inside framework module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776497/include-of-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it removing `Modules` folder from the framework.

- Browse to your framework location which is present in the App Project using finder
- Go inside `Test.framework` folder (In the above case it will be `mapFrameWork.framework`) & Delete `Modules` folder.
- Clean and Re Build the app, it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Add the header file to the Framework's umbrella header, and then add it to the Headers section as Public. In the below image it shows how to add Reachability library.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way I can do it with private or project target membership? I don't want the user to see any objective C file in my framework.

Answer (score -4):

Go to project -> Build Settings under "Target" and set "Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules" to YES.

Hope this will help.