# Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'AppLovinSDK' - Archive only error

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoapods, applovin

I get this error only when I try to archive, building for simulator or other test device works. Previously, I had this problem when trying to build for a test device, but I started over and reinstalled the pod and it worked. I have tried setting 'Allow non-modular Includes in Frameworks' to yes in both my project and Target, but this has NOT worked. Any ideas on how to get out of this would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: try adding those header files to the Headers section of your app under Build Phases, as [explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49810627/981049).

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? I'm having the same issue with a different framework when archiving

Comment: I did get it to work, but it was a random sequence of events that I did that I unfortunately don't remember off the top of my head. Although it only worked on the first build after installing the SDK if I remember correctly. Not stable and AppLovin's revenue ended up sucking so I abandoned them all together.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error (for archiving only) for my Swift framework with C code inside.

Only this remedy helped me.

Add `-Xcc -Wno-error=non-modular-include-in-framework-module` in `Other Swift Flags` (build settings of framework). This flag forces the compiller count that error as a warning.

[image]