# Getting error "Include of non-modular header inside framework module"

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, cocoapods, commoncrypto

I have a private pod written on top of [CommonCrypto](https://developer.apple.com/security/) which explicitly relies on CommonCrypto. Headers have types declared by CommonCrypto like:

```
#include <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

typedef CC_SHA256_CTX qwer_digest_evp;
```

Since `CC_SHA256_CTX` is declared in CommonCrypto, I can't simply move the header import into implementation file.

I use cocoapods to integrate this pod into my project, and tried the below post install hook, but it didn't work (picked from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45776870/1685709) ).

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      target.build_settings(config.name)['CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES'] = 'YES'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

An effective option might be to build a module version of `CommonCrypto` (maybe with added CocoaPods magic). This can be done by following the steps in the answer to [Importing CommonCrypto in a Swift framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50731485/542244). The solution functions just as well with Objective-C or C in your Xcode project.

To quote the answer:

> I've added some CocoaPods magic to [jjrscott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50256958/542244) in case you need to use CommonCrypto in your CocoaPods library.