# I am not able to compile my custom framework with MobileVLCKit in swift

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I want to create a custom framework using MobileVLCKit to run the RTSP stream URL, it's showing an error when I import `#import <MobileVLCKit/MobileVLCKit.h>` into my framework umbrella header.

error :
Include of non-modular header inside framework module `.../.../Pods/MobileVLCKit/MobileVLCKit.framework/Headers/MobileVLCKit.h'`

Comment: you can find some help from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776497/include-of-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module/31517439

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this issue?  I'm experiencing the same issue.