# Xcode - Include of non-modular header inside framework module error when archiving project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I'm currently trying to archive my project to finally update my app on the app store when I came across this issue.

I'm getting this error on multiple files in the [XlsxReaderWriter](https://github.com/renebigot/XlsxReaderWriter) framework.

`Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'XlsxReaderWriter.BRARelationship': '/Users/dannyespina/Documents/iOS_Applications/LoanMaster/loan-master/Pods/XMLDictionary/XMLDictionary/XMLDictionary.h'`

[image]

[image]

I had issues with this framework in the past but unfortunately this is the only one of it's kind that writes to excel files. I had to makes some changes in order for it work as shown [here](https://github.com/renebigot/XlsxReaderWriter/pull/44/files).

I tried everything to fixed this such as:

- setting "Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules" to YES to both the Pods project and LoanMaster
- Cleaning the project and deleting the derivedData a bunch of times
- Reinstalling Xcode.
- placing XMLDictionary.h as a public header as mentioned in one of the stack overflow answers
- Making sure that the framework is public
- Updated pods to the latest version (1.8.4)

The strange thing is that I archive this project in the past with this framework with the same exact changes to it. The library hasn't been updated in 3 years so nothing new should had cause this. Is this an issue with the new version of Xcode?

I really just want to update my app that I been working on for the past 6 months :(

Any help will be amazing!

---

Podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'LoanMaster' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for LoanMaster
  pod 'MPNumericTextField', '~> 1.4.0'
  pod 'Charts', '~> 3.2.1'
  pod 'LGButton'
  pod 'RealmSwift'
  pod 'SpreadsheetView'
  pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
  pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationMoPub'
  pod 'PersonalizedAdConsent'
  pod 'PopupDialog', '~> 1.1'
  pod 'NVActivityIndicatorView'
  pod 'FBAudienceNetwork'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
  pod 'XlsxReaderWriter', '~> 1.0'
  pod 'M13Checkbox'

    post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if ['SpreadsheetView', 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', 'NVActivityIndicatorView'].include? target.name
          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0'
          end
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['CLANG_WARN_DOCUMENTATION_COMMENTS'] = 'NO'
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Have you tried taking the project files out of Pods control, and add the Framework to your project directly?

Comment: I'll try removing XlsxReaderWriter from cocoapods and place it in my project and see if that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding XMLDictionary.h to my public headers for XlsxReaderWriter and changing import "XMLDictionary/XMLDictionary.h" back to "XMLDictionary.h".

I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37958447/3749869)

I hope this helps someone who's still using this old and forgotten framework.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this error because of react native image picker module.After lots of searches I changed its version to this "react-native-image-picker": "5.0.2". and the error resolved

```
yarn add react-native-image-picker@5.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove pod for XMLDictionary from podfile and add again it will be work.

Comment: my podfile doesn't contain XMLDictionary. That's derived from the XlsxReaderWriter framework itself. I updated my post with my podfile