# Install native iOS pod in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods, flutter-dependencies, flutter-plugin

I am facing an error while making a flutter plugin on the iOS side while using pods. The pods are installed successfully then also I am able to import them in the file.

The pod in my case which I am trying to use is [Freshchat iOS SDK](https://github.com/freshdesk/freshchat-ios)

Steps I have followed to install the pod

1. Start a new Flutter plugin project.
2. In `.podspec` file add `s.dependency 'FreshchatSDK'`
3. Run `pod install` in `example/ios` folder.

   I got an error

   `The 'Pods-Runner' target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries: (/Users/nimish/FlutterProjects/freshchat_flutter/freshchat_flutter/example/ios/Pods/FreshchatSDK/FreshchatSDK/libFDFreshchatSDK.a)`
4. I removed `use_frameworks!` from `podfile` following [this comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20045#issuecomment-409492211) .
5. I ran `pod install` again and the pods were successfully installed and `Pods` folder was created which had `FreshchatSDK` folder in it.

**Now I need to have `use_frameworks!` in my project because other plugins are not compiling because of this.**

1. I added `s.static_framework = true` in `.podspec` and `use_frameworks!` in `podfile`. Now `pod install` ran successfully,
2. After I added the import `#import "FreshchatSDK.h"` in my `Plugin.h` file I got the error

   `error: include of non-modular header inside framework module`

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776497/include-of-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module) but was not able to resolve it.

Please help me resolve this. I'll be respectful of your time.

There is another flutter plugin available [here](https://github.com/fayeed/flutter_freshchat) but it has many issues and one unhandled case is making my iOS app crash so I want to make it my own.

Answer (score 1):

There may be problems in the PodFile due to unmatched Targets.
When this happens to me, I used these simple steps.

1. Delete Podfile
2. Open Terminal at the specific file
3. `Pod init`
4. Open Podfile and adds Dependencies
5. `Pod install`