# How to set the modulemap for cocoapods project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I was trying to use a pod that was written in Obj-C and my project is Swift-only. 
I got this error `include of a non-modular header inside framework module` in the import statement of a dependency inside the framework .h file.

The pod spec of the [library](https://github.com/solid-software/flutter_vlc_player/) is:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'flutter_vlc_player'
  s.version          = '0.0.3'
  s.summary          = 'A new Flutter project.'
  s.description      = <<-DESC
A new Flutter project.
                       DESC
  s.homepage         = 'http://example.com'
  s.license          = { :file => '../LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Your Company' => 'email@example.com' }
  s.source           = { :path => '.' }
  s.source_files = 'Classes/**/*'
  s.public_header_files = 'Classes/**/*.h'
  s.dependency 'Flutter'

  s.dependency 'MobileVLCKit', '~> 3.3.10'
  s.static_framework = true

  s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'
end
```

The dependency is `MobileVLCKit`.

I found some reports about similar issues:

- https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7619
- https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8668
- [Importing CommonCrypto in a Swift framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248598/importing-commoncrypto-in-a-swift-framework/37125785#37125785)
- http://blog.cocoapods.org/Pod-Authors-Guide-to-CocoaPods-Frameworks/
- [Include of non-modular header inside framework module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776497/include-of-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module)

It seems like the Module Map of the project is missing, I want to do a PR to fix this in the library and it allows to work with Swift projects. However, I don’t know how I should configure the podspec of the library.
I’ve seen stuff like in the podspec:

```
s.script_phase = {  
    :name => 'CommonCrypto',    
    :script => 'COMMON_CRYPTO_DIR="${SDKROOT}/usr/include/CommonCrypto" 
    if [ -f "${COMMON_CRYPTO_DIR}/module.modulemap" ]   
        then    
        echo "CommonCrypto already exists, skipping"    
        else    
        # This if-statement means we will only run the main script if the   
        # CommonCrypto.framework directory doesn not exist because otherwise    
        # the rest of the script causes a full recompile for anything   
        # where CommonCrypto is a dependency    
        # Do a "Clean Build Folder" to remove this directory and trigger    
        # the rest of the script to run 
        FRAMEWORK_DIR="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/CommonCrypto.framework"    
        if [ -d "${FRAMEWORK_DIR}" ]; then  
            echo "${FRAMEWORK_DIR} already exists, so skipping the rest of the script." 
            exit 0  
        fi  
        mkdir -p "${FRAMEWORK_DIR}/Modules" 
        echo "module CommonCrypto [system] {    
            header \"${SDKROOT}/usr/include/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h\"   
            export *    
        }" >> "${FRAMEWORK_DIR}/Modules/module.modulemap"   
        ln -sf "${SDKROOT}/usr/include/CommonCrypto" "${FRAMEWORK_DIR}/Headers" 
    fi',    
    :execution_position => :before_compile  
  }
```

However , I don’t know how to properly do this.
Should I create a file called ModuleMap.h inside the library /Classes folder? And then put something like below?

framework module MixModuleFramework {
  umbrella header "MixModuleFramework.h"
  export *
  module * { export * }
}

I don’t want to use the Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules inside the project. I want to fix the library to its work with other projects.

When I try to run `pod lib lint --no-clean`

```
error: include of non-modular header inside framework module 'flutter_vlc_player.FlutterVlcPlayerPlugin': 'MobileVLCKit/MobileVLCKit.framework/Headers/MobileVLCKit.h' [-Werror,-Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module]
```

From Xcode errors:

```
Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'flutter_vlc_player.FlutterVlcPlayerPlugin': '/var/folders/k7/1ptshnq15zn3nz6bgp7sj8h88w6vb6/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20200423-87288-nosd33-flutter_vlc_player/Pods/MobileVLCKit/MobileVLCKit.framework/Headers/MobileVLCKit.h'
```

It seems that cocoapods auto generates some modulemap

```
framework module flutter_vlc_player {
  umbrella header "flutter_vlc_player-umbrella.h"

  export *
  module * { export * }
}
```

Still, I'm super noob on this modulemap issue and it does not allow projects that uses swift to build the app. So, how can I make the custom module app and let the podspec known that? Or, is there any other configuration that must to be done?

Comment: Module  map is needed only for modules written on Swift, for Objective-C they are not needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include of non-modular header inside framework module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776497/include-of-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module)

Comment: I want the library to be able to be imported by Swift-only app. The question did not help me much. The `pod lib lint` gives the error of not having the module map, also if you try to create a new project (swift-only) and attempt to import the library, you will get the error as well.