BoringSSL-GRPC unsupported option '-G' for target 'arm64-apple-ios15.0'
After updating to Xcode 16 Beta, when building an app, I get this error (in attachments). That's basically it. Is there any way to fix that or should I wait for BoringSSL update?
I've tried pod update and changing Minimum Deployment version. It didn't help.

Same issue for me after updating to XCode 16 beta with a flutter project.

I think the best option is to wait right now.
If you dont want to return to the previous version of MacOS like me, you can launch XCode 15.4 through Terminal.
./Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode

following up @walkman's comment. I'm able to run xcode with: open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode

If you are using Cocoapods this is a quick fix:
Add this to you Podfile ->
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'BoringSSL-GRPC'
      target.source_build_phase.files.each do |file|
        if file.settings && file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS']
          flags = file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'].split
          flags.reject! { |flag| flag == '-GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS' }
          file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'] = flags.join(' ')
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

After adding the above code > npx pod-install ./ios OR cd ./ios && pod install
This issue is from GRPC: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/36904

Solved with this solution. Thank you

Which part of the Podfile will this code be added?

I tried this fix but I keep getting error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found (in target 'webview_flutter_wkwebview' from project 'Pods')

what does this do exactly ??

This error happened for me after upgrading my mac to Sequoia 15 which forced me to install the newest xcode (version 16). This fix worked for me TYSM :)

upgraded to sequoia 15 and also xcode 16, I got hit with this issue on a flutter macos project. this is the correct fix. I tried some others just out of curiosity and none of them helped

This solved my problem. Thanks

This solution also solved my problem :)

Don't forget to run "pod install" after adding above lines in Podfile.

@KhawarShahzad your comment helped me

Thanks. Same issue for webcrypto package. Same solution. Just change the line to:
if target.name == 'webcrypto'

@RohintonCollins Could you suggest an edit for this?

@PeterShaburov As I said, same solution as above at the bottom of my podfile, just replace target.name == 'BoringSSL-GRPC' with target.name == 'webcrypto'

/Users/rgautam320/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/permission_handler_apple-9.1.4/ios/Classes/PermissionHandlerPlugin.h:1:9 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
Getting above error after adding the lines you have given

I'm using macOS 15.0 beta and Xcode 16 beta.
After few a hours I solved the problem with this:
Update CocoaPods
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod repo update

Then add changes above:
Before:
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '12.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end

After:
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  pod 'Firebase/Analytics', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'Firebase/Auth', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'Firebase/Core', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore', :modular_headers => true

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))

  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    if target.name == 'BoringSSL-GRPC'
      target.source_build_phase.files.each do |file|
        if file.settings && file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS']
          flags = file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'].split
          flags.reject! { |flag| flag == '-GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS' }
          file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'] = flags.join(' ')
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

At the end, clear pods and cache:
cd ios
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*

pod cache clean --all
pod install

This process ensures that your project uses the correct versions and configurations of the dependencies which should resolve the issues with building the iOS app.

This is what I did before posting my solution. Hopefully, this will be helpful for you and solve the problem.
First, I deleted the iOS and Android files from my project. Then, I navigated back to the folder where my project is located and recreated the project with the proper name.
Additionally, I made the following changes in my Runner.xcworkspace in targets:

Select Runner
Select runner from TARGETS
On the row select Build Settings and search for and set it to yes ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES = YES

P.S.: These are the commands I used from my terminal before posting my solution. After making these changes, the problem was resolved:
cd ios
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf Podfile.lock
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*

pod cache clean --all 
arch -x86_64 pod install 

brew install rbenv  

sudo gem install cocoapods 

flutter clean
flutter pub get 


This is not a universal fix. I am still running into issues.
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'firebase_storage.FLTTaskStateChannelStreamHandler':

I did add Firebase storage to the list of firebase services you explicitly set to use modular headers

I have added edits to my solution, including the remaining steps I took just before resolving my issue. Perhaps one of these steps also contributed to solving the problem. If I come up with anything else, I will try to help.

I believe the problem can be resolved by changing the setting in Xcode that I mentioned in the edit.

Running those end commands works for me. no need to change my PodFile Thanks @patryk

EDITI do need to change my PodFile

This worked after following the last steps of commands

Only this worked for me

Select runner from TARGETS
On the row select Build Settings and search for and set it to yes
ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES = YES

Mac 15.0
iOS Beta 18

I dont know what 1 or 2 means

what is runner?
"search for and set it to yes" search for what?


YES!  This worked for me too (along with the Podfile updates from Peter Shaburov in the accepted answer). Thanks @Deltrak.

I found this under Apple Clang - Language - Modules. The Setting was labeled Allow Non-modular Includes In Framework Modules.

There is no need to modify Pod file, just update all your firebase dependencies to the latest Nov 13, 2024. Then everything should work fine.

It worked for me. Thanks.

This, plus a few things, worked for me!
I had added Firebase Firestore to my pods.  Dependencies for that caused issues that led me here. I experimented with a few of the other, higher ranked answers until I saw this one.  After doing this, I needed to update my ios Target. I also needed to enable "Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules" as noted here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776497/include-of-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module
After that, I'm able to successfully build and run my app!

For me the only thing that worked is the podfile below, along with the commands that @Patryk posted.

cd ios
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf Podfile.lock
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
pod cache clean --all
arch -x86_64
pod install
brew install rbenv
sudo gem install cocoapods
flutter clean
flutter pub get


# platform :ios, '13.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  pod 'Firebase/Analytics', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'Firebase/Auth', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'Firebase/Core', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore', :modular_headers => true

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))

end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    if target.name == 'BoringSSL-GRPC'
      target.source_build_phase.files.each do |file|
        if file.settings && file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS']
          flags = file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'].split
          flags.reject! { |flag| flag == '-GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS' }
          file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'] = flags.join(' ')
        end
      end
    end
  end
end 


I tried pretty much everything in this thread, and it did not work until I added the following to my podfile (on top of Patryk's solution)
pod 'BoringSSL-GRPC', :modular_headers => true

If you are using flutter, The latest dependencies fixed this. So just update all firebase packages and flutter to latest version.
Flutter version
Flutter 3.24.3 • Dart 3.5.3 • DevTools 2.37.3

Dependencies
firebase_core: 3.6.0
firebase_auth: 5.3.1
cloud_firestore: 5.4.4
firebase_messaging: 15.1.3
firebase_storage: 12.3.3
cloud_functions: 5.1.3


Steps to Resolve the Issue:
step-1: Update cocoa pods-
sudo gem install cocoapods

pod repo update

Step-2 :
cd ios
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
pod cache clean --all

Step-3: then add those codes in Podfile file.
just replace this
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end

with this
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    if target.name == 'BoringSSL-GRPC'
      target.source_build_phase.files.each do |file|
        if file.settings && file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS']
          flags = file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'].split
          flags.reject! { |flag| flag == '-GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS' }
          file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'] = flags.join(' ')
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

step-4:
do that
 flutter clean
    flutter pub get 
    cd ios
    pod repo update
    pod install

After that, build clean and then build again in Xcode.
step-5:

Select a runner from TARGETS

On the row select Build Settings and search for and set it to yes
ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES = YES



Tested in Xcode-16.1
add the following codes at the end of the Podfile.
post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
 target.build_configurations.each do |config|
   config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
   config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
 end

 if target.name == 'BoringSSL-GRPC'
   target.source_build_phase.files.each do |file|
     if file.settings && file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS']
       flags = file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'].split
       flags.reject! { |flag| flag == '-GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS' }
       file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'] = flags.join(' ')
     end
   end
 end
end
end


  # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
  platform :ios, '16.0'

  # CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
  ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

  project 'Runner', {
    'Debug' => :debug,
    'Profile' => :release,
    'Release' => :release,
  }

  def flutter_root
    generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
    unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
      raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
    end

    File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
      matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
      return matches[1].strip if matches
    end
    raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
  end

  require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

  flutter_ios_podfile_setup

  target 'Runner' do
    use_frameworks!
    use_modular_headers!

    flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
    target 'RunnerTests' do
      inherit! :search_paths
    end
  end
  # Podfile
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      # Güncellenmiş kısım: Toolchain directory değişikliği
      xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
      if File.exist?(xcconfig_path)  # Dosyanın varlığını kontrol eder
        xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
        xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
        File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
      end

      # iOS Deployment Target'ı güncelle
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '16.0'

      # BoringSSL-GRPC için GCC Warn Inhibit All Warnings bayrağını kaldır
      if target.name == 'BoringSSL-GRPC'
        config.build_settings['GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS'] = 'NO'
      end
    end
  end

  # Flutter için ek yapılandırmalar (varsa)
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end

Just add the NO area :
if target.name == 'BoringSSL-GRPC'
        config.build_settings['GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS'] = 'NO'
      end


I implemented the indicated fix but unfortunately it doesn't work. Are there other solutions I can implement?

This pod file is working for Flutter Project
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'BoringSSL-GRPC'
      target.source_build_phase.files.each do |file|
        if file.settings && file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS']
          flags = file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'].split
          flags.reject! { |flag| flag == '-GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS' }
          file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'] = flags.join(' ')
        end
      end
    end
  end
end


I updated my Podfile to this: (2024-10-05)
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '18.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'BoringSSL-GRPC'
      target.source_build_phase.files.each do |file|
        if file.settings && file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS']
          flags = file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'].split
          flags.reject! { |flag| flag == '-GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS' }
          file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'] = flags.join(' ')
        end
      end
    end
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '18.0'
    end
  end
end

