# How to develop multi-language framework with objective-c and swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, frameworks

Well, I want to know how to move some parts of framework from objective-c to swift without big pain

Ok, as far as I know:

1) Any project not a framework.

- You make `Swift-Bridging-Header.h` or `CatsAndGuns-Bridging-Header.h` and put in it many import items.
- You assure yourself in Build Settings -> (Search Swift) -> Objective-C Bridging Header. And put here your name.
- Also check Packaging -> Defines Modules -> Yes

2) Framework

Well, you want to develop framework with mix objective-c and swift together.

And here you have pain: you can't use bridging headers in framework targets.

So, you come to google or documentation and start to read. [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

Ok, now you feel free and gorgeous about your knowledge, but.. you still don't know how to do it.

- Create umbrella header and name it: `YourProjectName-Swift.h`. `CatsAndGuns-Swift.h`, ok.
- Make it visible to framework level, so, navigate to right bar and put `target membership -> your_framework_target (CatsAndGuns.framework in my case, of course) -> Public`
- And everything should be ok? remember to put every import as: `#import <CatsAndGuns/Rocket.h>`

Ok, let's check Rocket.h file in our framework. it is a Project-visible file, so, can it be accessed via  in umbrella header (oh, `module-swift.h`) or not?

Now I have:

- No bridging header in project ( as i understand from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875745/xcode-6-beta-4-using-bridging-headers-with-framework-targets-is-unsupported) )
- Manually created umbrella header with project-visible `Rocket.h`: `#import <CatsAndGuns/Rocket.h>`
- errors in swift class that it can't see objective-c declarations.
- Product module name without spaces.

Comment: Do I read frustration in your question? :-) I went through this as well. By now, I think, it's currently not possible to expose private/internal headers/types within a framework. Still searching for an explanation of why a bridging-header can't be used in a framework. The generated "MyFramework-Swift.h"-header just works. So to make interoperability work in frameworks, all headers/types for mixed use have to be made public - which breaks a key-feature of frameworks.