# Swift: Dynamic Library And AFNetworking

Tags: swift, afnetworking, dynamic-library

I have a problem integrating AFNetworking in my Swift Dynamic Library:

Here is what I have done:

1. Create Xcode Project: ( Cocoa Touch Framework )
2. Initialize Pod: ( pod init ) via Terminal
3. Modify Podfile: Here is the content of the podfile, and execute (pod install)

   ```
   target 'MyFramework' do 
   use_frameworks!
   pod 'AFNetworking' => '~>2.0' 
   end
   ```
4. Create sample swift file "MyLibrary" with 1 method and property.
5. Import AFNetworking (import AFNetworking)
6. Build, and the sample "MyFramework.framework" has been created.
7. Create a new project file ( single application )
8. Drag "MyFramework.framework" to the new created project
9. Import MyLibrary: ( import MyLibrary ) in a viewcontroller class
10. Build.

Error:

> ld: framework not found AFNetworking for architecture armv7
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Have you consider using Alamofire (swift library equivalent to AFNetworking)? If you have real reasons of using AFNetworking then I think you are missing the bridging header part as described here : https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: Bridging file is not supported in creating Swift Dynamic Framework: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875745/xcode-6-beta-4-using-bridging-headers-with-framework-targets-is-unsupported

Using Alamofire will cause me to do lot of modification in my source file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dragged the framework you've built manually into the app project. This way Xcode won't know that it also needs `AFNetworking` as an additional dependency.

You have to use CocoaPods instead to add your framework to the app. This way you can declare `AFNetworking` as a dependency of your framework in it's `.podspec` file. CocoaPods will then link `AFNetworking` to the app.

See

- [Making a CocoaPod](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html)
- [Specs and the Specs Repo](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/specs-and-specs-repo.html)
- [Podspec Syntax Reference](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html)

Comment: Does it mean, I need to make my source available for public?

Comment: I have tried to install `AFNetwroking` using cocoapods in my client app, and it worked.

Comment: @Hokage can you just share the code how can you achieve this. or if possible share the demo app.