# iOS8: Custom Swift Framework accessing external framework written in Objective-C

Tags: ios8, frameworks, xcode6, couchbase-lite

I'm trying to create a custom framework called `CouchbaseKit` (a new target in Xcode) in Swift.  Inside my `CouchbaseKit`, I need to access `CouchBaseLite Framework` that's entirely written in **Obj-C**. I'm using `Cocoapods` to manage `CouchBaseLite` and a couple of other frameworks.  Below is my podfile.

**Podfile**

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
link_with ['CouchbaseKit']
# platform :ios, '8.0'

use_frameworks!
target 'CouchbaseDB' do
link_with ['CouchbaseKit']

pod 'couchbase-lite-ios'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.2.0'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.2'
pod 'XCGLogger', '~> 2.0'
end

target 'CouchbaseDBTests' do
end

target 'CouchbaseKit' do
end

target 'CouchbaseKitTests' do
end
```

Pods inside the project:

[image]

For my **TARGETS** I have the following settings in Build Phases.

**Define Module**  Yes

**Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules** Yes

**Problem:**
When I try to access the CouchbaseLite framework inside my CouchbaseKit (my custom framework), I get an error, "No such module 'CouchbaseLite' does not exist.

[image]

Tried:

1. Since the project is in Swift, I created an Objective-C File and Hit yes to "**Would you like to configure an Objective-C bridging header?**"
2. Even though Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules is set to YES in all targets, I still get an error when I try to `#import <CouchbaseLite/CouchbaseLite.h>` in `CouchbaseKit.h`
   [image]

Here is what my Build Phases looks like for my custom framework `CouchbaseKit`

[image]

**Question:**  How can I see an external Objective-C framework (CouchasebaseLite) in my custom Swift framework?

Comment: Try having a look at [this repo](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/Grocery-Sync-iOS/tree/swift) to see if you can get any clues from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Cocoapods 0.39 suffers from "Transitive Vendor Dynamic Libraries Unsupported"  You'll see this with the newest couchbase-lite-ios release including the binary CouchbaseLite.framework.  This unfortunately issue bit me so hard I had to refactor everything to use Carthage, and manually manage my frameworks in my final projects.

Speaking of which the binary released CouchbaseLite.framework is simply missing a module map.

Add one to: CouchbaseLite.framework/Modules/module.modulemap

```
framework module CouchbaseLite {
  umbrella header "CouchbaseLite.h"

  export *
  module * { export * }
}
```

You will then be able to include this framework into a bridging header, and have your dynamic framework nest properly. But you might need to switch to building your CouchbaseKit.framework to using Carthage like I did.

Comment: @Jens-Alfke I've noticed you mention it's available by default in swift global namespace in other comments, however I found it not appearing there, instead I had to add it to the bridging header and due to the missing modulemap you get a "No such module" error. This is in Xcode 7.1 beta 4, so maybe on prior Xcode releases you could be correct.

Comment: @orti How is Carthage working for you? Is it "I'll never go back to cocoapods again" good?

Comment: Carthage serves a good purpose, but right now (Nov 7, 2015) there's a lot of thrash in the development space around Xcode 7 and frameworks switching over from static libs to all dynamic.  So half the time a dependency just doesn't work. Xcode 7 is establishing a new standard, and eventually we'll all adopt dynamic frameworks.

Carthage's value is in pulling together dependencies quickly and keeping them all up to date.  Cocoapods does a better overall job for OSS but worse for deploying code in a client project with private code dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

CouchbaseLite on iOS is a static framework, i.e. its binary is a static library not a dylib. This means it's linked into your app as though it were a source file. For this reason you don't use `import` in Swift to access it; the classes are already in the same namespace as your app's classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use Cocoapods you can follow [this](https://marco.betschart.name/couchbaselite-module-maps)

Steps:

- Create a folder called the name of your Framework you want to use in
  that case `CouchbaseLite` and inside it create module map. The file name will be `module.map` and its content will be

module CouchbaseLite {
  header "../Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CouchbaseLite.h"
  export *
}

`Important Note: Don't add that folder to the project, I don't know why not when done it will not work`.

- Import Paths under Swift Compiler – Search Paths in your project settings. Use ${SRCROOT} in the module path (e.g. ${SRCROOT}/CouchbaseLite)
  [image].
- Then you can import it like any swift module.

Update: 
It will work nicely in Xcode, but when I have tried to validate the pod with the `pod lint` it still give error and I still don't know why.