# Cocoapods: Making a Cocoapod - Importing Alamofire and other Libraries

Tags: xcode6, dependencies, cocoapods

I'm trying to create a Cocoapod.  The files inside the library need access to Alamofire, SwiftyJSON, and XCGLogger Pods.

I have tried two approaches and they are both failing:

(1) Inside the Example project, I edited my Podfile to include:

```
pod 'couchbase-lite-ios'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.2.0'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.2'
pod 'XCGLogger', '~> 2.0'
```

Did `pod update` relaunched the Example Workspace.  Added files to the 'Development Pods' that use Alamofire, SwiftyJSON, XCGLogger, and Couchase, but I'm getting an error, `no such module found`.

(2)  I started a new project through `pod lib create` and this time I  manually dragged the frameworks mentioned above in Xcode, and still get the error no `such module found`.

[image]

[image]

Again, the files inside the Pods (or Library) that I'm trying to create can't seem to access Alamofire, SwiftyJSON, XCGLogger, and Couchase dependency.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey, were you able to get this working? Can you put your solution as an answer?

Comment: You can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688348/ios8-custom-swift-framework-accessing-external-framework-written-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

Add the dependency to your *.podspec file.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  ...
  s.dependency 'Alamofire'
  s.dependency 'SwiftyJSON'
  s.dependency 'XCGLogger'
  s.dependency 'couchbase-lite-ios'
  ...
end
```