# error: using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have a `Objective C Cocoa Framework` I want to use a `Swift` file in my `framework` but I added a `Bridging Header` file with name `<Project-name>-Swift.h` line. But, when I run it, the output is:

> :0: error: using bridging headers with framework targets is
>   unsupported

Comment: set path for bridging header

Comment: i did this but same error agaion

Comment: @ user3036749 - May be you deleted your framework but reference is still available .Remove your frameworks from your project then again add framework then clean your project then build your project .It will work fine.Happy coding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 6 / Beta 4: using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875745/xcode-6-beta-4-using-bridging-headers-with-framework-targets-is-unsupported)

Answer (score 2):

**umbrella framwork solves**

- bridging headers for projects
- umbrella  file for frameworks

---

here is an example:

two files needed

> fisherWebP-umbrella.h

&

> fisherWebP.modulemap

[image: 111]

where to place them

[image: 00]

in fisherWebP.modulemap:

```
framework module Kingfisher{
  umbrella header "fisherWebP-umbrella.h"

  export *
  module * { export * }
}
```

in fisherWebP-umbrella.h

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#else
#ifndef FOUNDATION_EXPORT
#if defined(__cplusplus)
#define FOUNDATION_EXPORT extern "C"
#else
#define FOUNDATION_EXPORT extern
#endif
#endif
#endif



#import "demux.h"
#import "mux.h"
#import "decode.h"
// what you need
```

in Xcode,

you need fisherWebP-umbrella.h

not fisherWebP.modulemap

[image: 00099]

**then** set fisherWebP-umbrella.h

in `settings` , `Packaging Options`,

[image: 999]

**PS:**

you need set fisherWebP-umbrella.h as public

[image: 99999]

files imported in  fisherWebP-umbrella.h, should set as public too.

such as : demux.h

[image: 888]

do this recursively.

**PPS:**

set `OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS` to `-Xcc -Wno-error=non-modular-include-in-framework-module` inhibit swift import error.

( Include of non-modular header inside framework module
)