# CocoaPod Include of non-modular header inside framework module

Tags: swift3, cocoapods, objc-bridging-header

I am making a open-source library in Swift, it uses a third-party library ([MailCore](https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2)) which is itself in Obj-C so I added a bridging-header in my library.

The library is itself working fine when I run in my example project but when I try to use it as a CocoaPod in a Swift project then the compiler shows the following error:

`Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'MyLib.MyLib_Bridging_Header': 'path/to/my/otherProject/Pods/Headers/Public/mailcore2-ios/MailCore/MailCore.h'`

P.S - I am using my library in a Swift project using cocoa pods using `use_frameworks!`

Can you please help me in solving this issue?

**Edit :**

I have no intention to make it as a framework , this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875745) is regarding the frameworks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift compiler error: “non-modular header inside framework module”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103169/swift-compiler-error-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module)

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/499581/lll  I have no intention to make it as a framework , this question is regarding the frameworks.

Comment: If you have no intention of making it a framework why would do "use_frameworks!" in CocoaPods?

Comment: because Swift project requires use of  "use_frameworks!"

Answer (score 2):

I solved it removing `Modules` folder from the framework.

- Browse to your framework location which is present in the App Project using finder
- Go inside `Test.framework` folder (In the above case it will be `MailCore.framework`) & Delete `Modules` folder.
- Clean and Re Build the app, it will solve the problem.